# The way to file a new-package request ("RFP") with the Chocolatey team

Tags: windows, package-management, chocolatey, issue-tracking

If you're using Debian Linux and `apt-get`, and you want to ask the Debian team to create a new package, you file a [Debian RFP bug](https://wiki.debian.org/RFP).

If you're using Fedora Linux and `yum`, you visit the [Package Database homepage](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/) and click the "Request new package" button.

What if you're using Windows and Chocolatey? How can you ask them to please package some software for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted, you could [create and submit a package yourself](https://chocolatey.org/docs/package-triage-process#package-request-package-missing).

But, if you don't want to do this, visit the [chocolatey-package-requests GitHub page](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-package-requests), then scroll down and read the RFP instructions.